# Compare Huge XML files

Tags: xml, compare

I need to view XML files, each of 3-4 GB.

Could anybody tell me best free tool/trial version to view huge size XML because if I open it in some editor, its giving me "Out of memory"? I need the pretty-print option as well in it. I tried 010 Editor but it doesn't have pretty-print option in it.

Comment: vi can open files of any size

Comment: whats vi, and where to download it from?

Answer (score 0):

[Vi IMproved](http://www.vim.org/) will happily open files of any size.
It also has useful search&replace functionality.

Assuming you're working on a 64bit PC, you should download the [64 bit version](http://code.google.com/p/vim-win3264/).

Comment: Could you please tell me the syntax to use it? Its not working at my end.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.unix-manuals.com/tutorials/vi/vi-in-10-1.html or http://www.eng.hawaii.edu/Tutor/vi.html

Comment: I have updated the question, I am really grateful to ur response.